# Django path in Mac OS X

Tags: python, django

I installed django and want to specify its path in my mac, and I put the path into .profile and also checked with $PATH to ensure that is specified. However, when I go to python's environment and type import django, it cannot find. Have no idea about that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Err... what happened to your text? Can you reformat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to go in `$PYTHONPATH` instead.  Create that variable if it's not already defined.